# How to identify if an injected object is a Singleton object or a Transient one in debug mode in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I had this wrong code in program.cs where I had registered IService1 in the `AddHttpClient` line of code and being unaware that it also registers the underlying type (i.e. Service1) in DI as Transient, I also erroenously had the `AddSingleton` line of code on the same type as well.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService1, Service1>
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttphandler() {UseCookies= false});
```

followed by:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
```

With the code above, albeit an erroneous one, If I set my breakpoint on the constructor of Service1 class and watch the injected HttpClient, how can I know if the injected HttpClient is a Singleton object vs not in the Watch window, as it is injected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator?view=netcore-3.1) class to generate the ObjectIDs same as [MakeObjectID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2022) in Visual Studio for .Net Framework. If you get the same ID then it's a singleton other wise you can assume that it was transient object. Here's a quick snippet I created to test it out.

```
    var id = new System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator();
    var obj1 = id.GetId(Container.GetInstance<HttpClient>(), out bool firstTime);
    var obj2 = id.GetId(Container.GetInstance<HttpClient>(), out firstTime);
    (obj1.Equals(obj2)).Dump("obj1.Equals(obj2)");

    var obj3 = id.GetId(Container.GetInstance<DbContext>(), out firstTime);
    var obj4 = id.GetId(Container.GetInstance<DbContext>(), out firstTime);
    (obj3.Equals(obj4)).Dump("obj3.Equals(obj4)");
```

Comment: Ok. Will try this out tomorrow. Appreciate it, @Guru Stron, again!

Answer (score 3):

You don't, and by DI's design you shouldn't know.

What you seem to want here is actually a code analysis module that finds these kinds of issues and highlights them for you (potentially even auto-fix them for you, too). It shouldn't be difficult to write, there's only a few different functions to monitor.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks @Blindy! Let me try to google it. I never had to know if an object I was 'Quick Watching' was Static or not, ever. But this scenario did set me thinking, as this was the DI Blackbox that is weaving its magic here.

Answer (score 1):

> If I set my breakpoint on the constructor of Service1 class and watch the injected HttpClient, how can I know if the injected HttpClient is a Singleton object vs not in the Watch window, as it is injected.

First of all if `Service1` is a singleton it does not matter how dependency is registered - transient or singleton, it will any way become [captive dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#captive-dependency).

As for `HttpClient` itself, first of all it is injected in quite peculiar way via `AddHttpClient` (you can take a deep dive into [the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,234)) and when you will override the `IService1` registration with extra `Add...` this will result in `HttpClient` missing all the setup, so you can check that:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
services.AddSingleton<IClient, Client>();
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var service = sp.GetService<IClient>();
Console.WriteLine(service.BaseAddress); // will print empty string

interface IClient
{
    string? BaseAddress { get; }
}

class Client : IClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public Client(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public string? BaseAddress => _client.BaseAddress?.ToString();
}
```

There are not much other things you can do inside service ctor, but you can play with either service collection after all registration are done:

```cs
var serviceDescriptors = services.Where(sc => sc.ServiceType == typeof(IClient))
    .ToList(); // will contain 2 service descriptors for snippet above
```

Or create two custom scopes resolve 2 instances in one and another one in the second scope and compare them with `object.ReferenceEquals()`.

Comment: Thanks @Guru! Had never heard of captive dependency! Appreciate your response!

Comment: Just to confirm if others are reading, the Service1 class itself is not a Singleton class and it's just a simple class with methods that all make calls to another API. But this is fascinating to know, as I genuinely thought the second line, which is AddSingleton line will override the Transient behavior, as it comes after the AddHttp line.  It is great to know this and that was the main point why I asked this question.